# Quadratic Taylor approximation of an integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, multivalued-functions

I'm trying to find the quadratic Taylor approximation of $$f(x,y)=\int_0^{x+y^2}e^{-t^2}dt$$about the point $(0,0)$. I really don't know how to solve this though since I don't know even if it's possible to find the partial derivative of an integral. If anyone could provide any advice or hints, that would be great.

Comment: Start considering the one-variable function $F(s)=\int_0^s e^{-t^2}\,dt$. You can easily Taylor expand this by integrating termwise.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how you would integrate even the one-variable function.

Comment: Taylor expand $e^{-x^2}$, then integrate termwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $E(s) = \int_0^{s}e^{-t^2}\,dt$
$$f(x,y) = \int_0^{x+y^2}e^{-t^2}\,dt = E(x + y^2).$$
By the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
\partial_x f(x,y) = E'(x + y^2)\partial_x(x + y^2) =
 e^{-(x+y^2)^2}.
$$
$$\cdots$$